# How to connect on premise (Power BI Report Server) from Excel using the Power BI publisher for Excel add-in?

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I have Power BI report server setup in my on-premise environment. Here I am trying to connect to the PowerBI report server (on-premise) via the Excel sheet add-in (Power BI publisher for Excel).

I followed the below mentioned article :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/publisher-for-excel

But in this case I am not able to connect to the on premise PowerBI report server. It is always connecting me with the cloud version of PowerBI.

Can any one help me to know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently PowerBI addon - publisher-for-excel only Support for PowerBI services not for desktop/On-premises/Report servers.

Answer (score 0):

As it mentioned in the description that *When you pin an element from Excel, a new tile is added to a new or existing **dashboard** in Power BI*,

In our case the dashboard feature it-self would not be available in Power BI report server. Eventually, publisher for excel would not be in the consideration with Power BI Report server. [For full features list..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/compare-report-server-service)